# TLS session resumption with HAproxy load balancer

Tags: session, ssl, haproxy

After configuring application to work with TLS CPU consumption has got up to 10%. 
I suppose it is because of TLS Handshake that happens every time.

On standalone environment I don't have such an effect. But when I am trying to use HAProxy LB it seems to me that session is cached for one node however when request came to another it need to perform handshake again.

How can I configure LB or tune it in order to avoid extra handshakes?

Tried to increase session cache it does't help.

> tune.ssl.cachesize
>
> tune.ssl.lifetime

Comment: Caching a session for one node is enough if you use _sticky sessions_.

Comment: what does it mean sticky sessions, and could you please give more info how to do it?